# Finding the value of polynomial at a particular value / constant is given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $P(k)$ is a polynomial of degree $8$ and $P(k) = \frac{1}{k}$ for $k = 1,2 ,3,\ldots,9$ then find the value of $P(10)$.

As we know the following :

$f(x) =a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.....a_1x+a_0$

Can we use this...or some other alternate method.. Please suggest

Comment: You know what $n$ is?

Comment: You can certainly Lagrange interpolate. But there is probably a smarter way.

Comment: If you can find *any* polynomial of degree 8 (or less) that agrees on those 9 values, then $P(x)$ must be identical to that polynomial.

Comment: @julien: I'm not sure it's helpful (and I certainly wouldn't want to solve it), since we know $P(x)$ for $9$ values, can't we form a system of equations and solve for the coefficients of $P(x)$? I may be totally in the wrong and am too tired to think straight. I think this is true simply because we know $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $8$, hence it has $9$ coefficients.

Comment: @julien: Just a few moments. I'll check.

Comment: @julien: I don't have the appropriate software to enter such a system, and I couldn't quickly find one that was suitable. I tried a free online linear system solver, but I don't think it could handle it. I'll look for a bit longer.

Comment: @Clayton No worries, it is confirmed by Mathematica and Antonio Vargas, modulo a prior mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php which gives (x^8-45x^7+870x^6-9450x^5+63273x^4-269325x^3+723680x^2-1172700x+1026576)/9!, that also confirms 1/5 answer.

Answer (score 2):

After all, this was maybe an exercise on [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) and the binomial theorem, as things work out nicely this way.
Let
$$
L_k(x):=\frac{\prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^9(x-j)}{\prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^9(k-j)}\qquad k=1,\ldots,9.
$$
Each $L_k$ is a degree $8$ polynomial which gives $1$ at $k$ and $0$ on $\{1,\ldots,9\}\setminus\{k\}$. Therefore, we have
$$
P(x)=\sum_{k=1}^9\frac{1}{k}\;L_k(x)
$$
as these two degree $8$ polynomials agree on $9$ distinct values. Now we can compute
$$
P(10)=\sum_{k=1}^9\frac{1}{k}\frac{\prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^9(10-j)}{\prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^9(k-j)}
=\sum_{k=1}^9\frac{1}{k}\frac{\frac{9!}{10-k}}{(k-1)!(-1)^{9-k}(9-k)!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^9 \binom{10}{k}(-1)^{k+1}
=\frac{1}{10}\Big(2-\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(-1)^k\Big)=\frac{1}{10}\Big(2-(1-1)^{10}\Big)=\frac{1}{5}.
$$

Comment: Using Mathematica to compute the interpolating polynomial I get $P(10) = 1/5$.  (sorry for deleting/recommenting!)

Comment: Spotted it: Instead of $10!/(10-k)$ it should be $9!/(10-k)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Great catch! Thanks a lot.